# Draw TextView around a specific point

Tags: android, textview

Is there a way to center text around a certain point? So for example if I want it to draw around  the 100th pixel it would then make 100 the center point regardless of the length of the text, so if the text was 80 pixels it would start at 60 and end at 140, but if the text was only 50 pixels it would start at 75 and end at 125.

This is the code I am currently using to draw text.

```
public TextView drawTextView(String text, boolean center, int centerPoint, boolean bold, int topMargin, int leftMargin, int textSize, int color) {
    View vt = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    final TextView textView = new AutoResizeTextView(vt.getContext());

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Quicksand-Regular.otf");

    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setTextColor(color);
    if (bold) {
        textView.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
    } else {
        textView.setTypeface(tf);
    }

    textView.setTextSize(textSize);
    textView.setSingleLine(false);

    LayoutParams paramsText = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsText.leftMargin = leftMargin;
    paramsText.topMargin = topMargin;
    container.addView(textView, paramsText);

    return textView;

}
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this in Android but any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
textView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int width = textView.getMeasuredWidth();
textView.setX(centerPoint - width * 0.5F)
```